# didReceiveNotificationResponse method is not called when the app gets launched through notification swipe from a closed state

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have observed that `didReceiveNotificationResponse` method is called when I re-launch the app from the background through a push notification swipe. But it is not getting called when I closed the app and re-launched through a push notification swipe.

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
    withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
    {
       // Sending analytics to my server
 }
```

I am verifying this through my analytics backend and I can see all the launches from the background through notification swipe are reflected but the other one is not. In both cases, I am hitting the same API, so ideally it should get updated.

The following is my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*) launchOptions
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //Run UI Updates
    if (@available(iOS 10, *)) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if( !error ) {
            // required to get the app to do anything at all about push notifications
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            });
            NSLog( @"Push registration success." );
        } else {
            NSLog( @"Push registration FAILED" );
            NSLog( @"ERROR: %@ - %@", error.localizedFailureReason, error.localizedDescription );
            NSLog( @"SUGGESTIONS: %@ - %@", error.localizedRecoveryOptions, error.localizedRecoverySuggestion );
        }
        }];
    }
});
```

Adding my notification content I am getting from a third-party service provider (Salesforce):

```
{
    "_h" = "V6bdjs7jjkqv/POIIIII";
    "_m" = MjJhJkKkK;
    "_mt" = 1;
    "_r" = "9dsdsjkk-3344dd-4edd-ade33-jhdj999";
    "_sid" = SFMC;
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = test;
            subtitle = "Push Test";
            title = "Push Test";
        };
        "mutable-content" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
}
```

I have enabled `Remote Notifications` from `Background Modes` also.

[image]

Comment: What was the state of application at the time when you tap on the notification?

Comment: Was it Not launched?

Comment: You need to use launch option to check app is launched through notification or not and based on that just check notification data.

Comment: I saw a couple of answers with that solution. But, to make my analytics work I need to pass `notification.response.notification.request`. I will not get this data from `launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]`, right? Is there any way to get that? Then I can handle it from a custom function.

Comment: What is inside of `notification.response.notification.request`? You can get all information about your notification inside Launch option.

Comment: `launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]` is returning the same json that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: `notification.response.notification.request` is this: 
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x282bc0ab0; identifier: FAQW35E-AD544-876E-B54D-1FFF43247DC44, content: <UNNotificationContent: 0x281c52220; title: <redacted>, subtitle: <redacted>, body: <redacted>, summaryArgument: (null), summaryArgumentCount: 0, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x280c4ea70>,, trigger: <UNPushNotificationTrigger: 0x28254de00; contentAvailable: NO, mutableContent: YES>>

How do I get this in launchOptions?

Comment: so after 2 years... did you find a solution for that? we're having the same problem.

Comment: @P.Melch We were facing the issue with salesforce-marketing-cloud sdk. Later we discontinued using them and shifted to a new vendor [MoEngage]. We didn't face this issue then.